# I want to split data in 1 cell in excel to multiple columns. What options do I have to do this? SQL? Python? Excel?

Tags: sql, excel

I have data in excel in 1 cell as:

```
1MLB564,6080.045%21.868,163,863+0.08%
```

How to make it look in columns as:

```
1   MLB   564,608   0.045%   21.86   8,163,863  +0.08%
```

Any suggestions how to do it in excel or sql.

Comment: Unless you have something that denotes where the string should break(a special character or fixed character counts) this will be nearly impossible in either.

Comment: Well, looking at your first 2 columns, you don't seem to have a clear delimeter, but you could use a decent IDE, open your spreadsheet as CSV and run a preg_replace?

Comment: In Excel, you can do Data->Text to Columns, but as Prof83 noted, without a consistent delimiter, you'd have to do it in stages.

Comment: This is easy to do if the fields have a specific defined length.

Answer (score 0):

Place your field widths in **B1** through **H1** and your data in **A2**

In **B2** enter:

```
=LEFT($A$2,B1)
```

In **C2** enter:

```
=MID($A$2,SUM($B$1:B1)+1,C1)
```

and copy across:

[image]

If you cannot define the field widths, ignore this answer.